# Xpath find specific value and values of other tags in the same tree

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Using PHP, SimpleXML and XPATH; I want to find a specific serviceId and then find the DMA and Abbreviation values. I can find a specific serviceId using `$xml->xpath(//d:ServiceId[.= '123'])`, but I am not sure how to modify the xpath query to also return the DMA and Abbreviation as well.

```
<?xml>
    <feed xmlns:m="" xmlns:d="">
        <entry>
            <content>
                <m:properties>
                    <d:ServiceId>123</d:ServiceId>
                    <d:ServiceName>Service 1</d:ServiceName>
                    <d:DMA>DMA 1</d:DMAName>
                    <d:Abbreviation>ABC</d:Abbreviation>
                </m:properties>
            </content>
            <content>
                <m:properties>
                    <d:ServiceId>456</d:ServiceId>
                    <d:ServiceName>Service 2</d:ServiceName>
                    <d:DMA>DMA 2</d:DMAName>
                    <d:Abbreviation>DEF</d:Abbreviation>
                </m:properties>
            </content>
            <content>
                <m:properties>
                    <d:ServiceId>789</d:ServiceId>
                    <d:ServiceName>Service 3</d:ServiceName>
                    <d:DMA>DMA 3</d:DMAName>
                    <d:Abbreviation>HIJ</d:Abbreviation>
                </m:properties>
            </content>
        </entry>
    </feed>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `m:properties` node first. To get it use this XPath:

```
//m:properties[d:ServiceId = 123]
```

After that just query this node to retrieve `d:DMA` and `d:Abbreviation` elements. Sorry, I don't know PHP but it should be straightforward.

As alternative try this XPath with union operator:

```
//m:properties[d:ServiceId = 123]/d:DMA | //m:properties[d:ServiceId = 123]/d:Abbreviation
```